# Latest symbol is lost in Word equation after Professional to Linear (LaTeX) conversion

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, latex, equations, equation-editor

I enter the formula in the latest Word for Office 365 (version 2003 (not Word 2003, the 2020 year version), build 12624) in LaTeX mode:

```
\frac{x}{y}=\alpha
```

It converts to Professional look normally, but if I switch again to Linear and back to Professional, the alpha symbol is lost. Sometimes it is lost just after entering and the first conversion.

If it is `\alpha^2` everything is OK.
I can put just `^` at the end without a number, but it looks like an unfinished equation.

Does any other workaround exist to prevent missing symbols in equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same version of Office 365，and found this issue exists when I convert to Professional first time.

[image]

I need to add a symbol like ";" behind "\alpha" in Linear mode.

After convert to Professional, delete the symbol, then try to **press Space key** behind **α**.

The following gif shows after doing that, the equation switch correctly.

[image]

When converting to Linear, "\" represents space, but entering "\" in Linear mode does not work as we need.

Comment: Thanks! I found that "\ " (slash and space) in linear mode also work.